# How do i take matching values in [Col A] with their corresponding score in [Col b] from 6 separate data frames and create new df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-analysis

I have 6 different data frames. Each data frame is a specific parameter pertaining to traits of countries around the world (i.e. a military data frame that lists a col of countries and then a col of their corresponding military score, or a population data frame that lists a col of country names and a col of their corresponding population score). In my resulting program, I want to compare each country in a final data frame using the scores from each of the 6 parameters. However, each parameter data frame has a different number of countries. For example, population has 232 country names, but military only has 135. Because of this, the resulting data frame displaying each country and all of their corresponding scores do not match up properly. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a logical or efficient way I can locate each country and pull their scores in each parameter data frame and save it to the final df? I'm thinking a conditional statement or iloc?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're looking for a merge. You'll have to play around with what kind of merge you use (pd.merge() takes a paramer: how=left/right maybe inner)